# Minimum sum that cant be obtained from a set

Tags: algorithm

Given a set S of positive integers whose elements need not to be distinct i need to find  minimal non-negative sum that cant be obtained from any subset of the given set.

Example : `if S = {1, 1, 3, 7}`,  we can get `0` as `(S' = {})`, `1` as `(S' = {1})`, `2` as `(S' = {1, 1})`, `3` as `(S' = {3})`, `4` as `(S' = {1, 3})`, `5` as `(S' = {1, 1, 3})`, but we can't get `6`.

Now we are given one `array A`, consisting of `N` positive integers. Their are `M` queries,each consist of two integers `Li` and `Ri` describe i'th query: we need to find this Sum that  cant be obtained from array `elements ={A[Li], A[Li+1], ..., A[Ri-1], A[Ri]}` .

I know to find it by a brute force approach to be done in O(2^n). But given `1 ≤ N, M ≤ 100,000`.This cant be done .
So is their any effective approach to do it.

Comment: This is [ForbiddenSum](http://www.codechef.com/JAN14/problems/FRBSUM) problem from running CodeChef contest. IMHO most interesting problem in this contest.

Comment: Why is it that we can't get 6 if we could form s'={3,3}?

Comment: @EmmadKareem Because there is only one 3 in the list.

Comment: @EmmadKareem Their is only 1 three available in the set.How can u make {3,3}?

Comment: The question mentions "any subset" in the text. It may be worth mentioning that repetitions are not allowed.

Comment: @EmmadKareem is {3,3} subset of this set according to you?.I think you are misinterpreting the question

Comment: What I don't understand is why this has so many downvotes. It's an interesting problem, to say the least. And the question is completely clear.

Comment: Is there a limit to the size of the integers? Or are any integers valid?

Comment: @NikoDrašković yeah 1 ≤ Ai ≤ 10^9 and 1 ≤ A1 + A2 + ... + AN ≤ 10^9

Comment: possible duplicate of [Smallest number that can not be formed from sum of numbers from array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21077763/smallest-number-that-can-not-be-formed-from-sum-of-numbers-from-array)

Comment: @Shepmaster This was asked *before* that one

Comment: @NikoDrašković that's true, but this question does not have an upvoted or accepted answer (SO's rules for duplicates).

Comment: @NikoDrašković Likely because, at the time of asking, this was a question from an active programming contest. While users can't justifiable vote to close the question for this reason, as [so] doesn't explicitly forbid these question, they can downvote it to encourage self-deletion and discourage similar scenario's in future.

Answer (score 15):

### Concept

Suppose we had an array of `bool` representing which numbers so far haven't been found (by way of summing).

[image: numbers array]

For each number `n` we encounter in the **ordered** (increasing values) subset of `S`, we do the following:

1. For each existing `True` value at position `i` in `numbers`, we set `numbers[i + n]` to `True`
2. We set `numbers[n]` to `True`

With this sort of a sieve, we would mark all the *found* numbers as `True`, and iterating through the array when the algorithm finishes would find us the minimum unobtainable sum.

---

### Refinement

Obviously, we can't have a solution like this because the array would have to be infinite in order to work for all sets of numbers.

The concept could be improved by making a few observations. With an input of `1, 1, 3`, the array becomes (in sequence):

[image]<sup>(numbers represent `true` values)</sup> 
[image]
[image: numbers array 2]

An important observation can be made:

- (3) For each next number, if the previous numbers had already been found it will be added to all those numbers. This implies that **if there were no gaps before a number, there will be no gaps after that number has been processed**.

For the next input of `7` we can assert that:

- (4) Since the input set is ordered, there will be no number less than `7`
- (5) If there is no number less than `7`, then `6` cannot be obtained

[image]

We can come to a conclusion that:

- (6) **the first gap represents the minimum unobtainable number**.

---

### Algorithm

Because of (3) and (6), we don't actually need the `numbers` array, we only need a single value, `max` to **represent the maximum number found so far**.

This way, if the next number `n` is greater than `max + 1`, then a gap would have been made, and `max + 1` is the minimum unobtainable number.

Otherwise, `max` becomes `max + n`. If we've run through the entire `S`, the result is `max + 1`.

Actual code (C#, easily converted to C):

```
static int Calculate(int[] S)
{
    int max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < S.Length; i++)
    {
        if (S[i] <= max + 1)
            max = max + S[i];
        else
            return max + 1;
    }
    return max + 1;
}
```

Should run pretty fast, since it's obviously linear time (O(n)). Since the input to the function should be sorted, with quicksort this would become O(nlogn). I've managed to get results `M = N = 100000` on 8 cores in just under 5 minutes.

With numbers upper limit of 10^9, a radix sort could be used to approximate O(n) time for the sorting, however this would still be way over 2 seconds because of the sheer amount of sorts required.

***But***, we can use **statistical probability of 1 being randomed** to eliminate subsets *before* sorting. On the start, check if 1 exists in `S`, if not then every query's result is 1 because it cannot be obtained.

Statistically, if we random from 10^9 numbers 10^5 times, we have 99.9% chance of not getting a single 1.

Before each sort, check if that subset contains 1, if not then its result is one.

With this modification, the code runs in 2 miliseconds on my machine. Here's that code on http://pastebin.com/rF6VddTx

Comment: The sorting is the slow part here, without it this would be blazing. But under 2 seconds I don't think you'll be able to iterate through all the arrays, let alone find the result.

Comment: @user119249 I've put in an update that makes it run in 2 miliseconds. Still, the worst can take hours but it's extremely unlikely that will happen

Answer (score 2):

**This is a variation of the [subset-sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem)**, which is [NP-Complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete), but there is a pseudo-polynomial [Dynamic Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) solution you can adopt here, based on the recursive formula:

```
f(S,i) = f(S-arr[i],i-1) OR f(S,i-1)
f(-n,i) = false
f(_,-n) = false
f(0,i) = true
```

The recursive formula is basically an exhaustive search, each sum can be achieved if you can get it with element `i` OR without element `i`.

The dynamic programming is achieved by building a `SUM+1 x n+1` table (where `SUM` is the sum of all elements, and `n` is the number of elements), and building it bottom-up.

Something like:

```
table <- SUM+1 x n+1 table
//init:
for each i from 0 to SUM+1:
    table[0][i] = true
for each j from 1 to n:
    table[j][0] = false
//fill the table:
for each i from 1 to SUM+1:
    for each j from 1 to n+1:
         if i < arr[j]:
              table[i][j] = table[i][j-1]
         else:
              table[i][j] = table[i-arr[j]][j-1] OR table[i][j-1]
```

Once you have the table, you need the smallest `i` such that for all `j`:  `table[i][j] = false`

Complexity of solution is `O(n*SUM)`, where `SUM` is the sum of all elements, but note that the algorithm can actually be trimmed after the required number was found, without the need to go on for the next rows, which are un-needed for the solution.

Comment: If this is indeed [this problem](http://www.codechef.com/JAN14/problems/FRBSUM), `n*SUM` can be as large as `10^15`, which would take a bit long, I think. Also, you are given many queries of ranges for which you need to find the sum, and I don't think this solution can efficiently be converted to that (but I may be wrong).

Comment: @amit Yeah i agree with Dukeling.Is their any better way?How can i built such large 2d array