# All possible numbers formed from addition of given digits

Tags: c++, algorithm

If I have `n-r` numbers, from `1 to n` where `r` numbers are missing in between, then how can I calculate all possible numbers that can be formed from addition of these numbers (either in groups of 2/3/4/5/6...).

For example, lets say I have `5-2` numbers, 
that is, `1 2 4` and `3 5` are missing. Now, I can form

```
1 - {1}
2 - {2}
3 - {1,2}
4 - {4}
5 - {1,4}
6 - {4,2}
7 - {1,2,4}
8 - Cannot be formed
```

This is I need to find out, that is the first number from 1 which I cannot form using the combination of the given digits. A simple logic would do fine. Thanks!

Comment: Do you just want the first number you can't form? Or all the numbers you can't form? Or all the numbers you can form?

Comment: Just the first number that I cannot form is of interest to me. That's it.

Comment: I suggest developing an *algorithm* using pen and paper first, then implementing.

Comment: What logic do I use for it? I am not asking for a code, but simply a logic that I can use.

Comment: *8 - Cannot be formed but 8 can be formed by addition of group {6,2} ?

Comment: That is what I have written, we only have numbers from 1 to n out of which some numbers are missing. In the example, we have numbers from 1 to 5 from which 2 numbers have been deleted and we have to find out the result from the reamining numbers.

Comment: @JohnYad What would you want the answer to be if your numbers were {1, 2, 3} and you had to form a 3?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21077763/smallest-number-that-can-not-be-formed-from-sum-of-numbers-from-array/21078133#21078133

Answer (score 0):

Let `S[i]` be the set of numbers that can be formed from the first `i` of your numbers. Then given `S[i]`, it is easy to construct `S[i+1]`: start with `S[i]`, and then add all numbers of the form `s+r`, where `s` is in `S[i]` and `r` is the `(i+1)`-th number in your list.

Thus you can iteratively build the sets `s[0] = {0}, S[1],...,S[n-r]`, and `S[n-r]` contains all possible sums.

Here is how your example plays out:

```
S[0] = {0}
r = 1: S[1] = {0} union {0+1} = {0,1}
r = 2: S[2] = {0,1} union {0+2,1+2} = {0,1,2,3}
r = 4: S[3] = {0,1,2,3} union {0+4,1+4,2+4,3+4} = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Start with a `set` containing 0
2. Find all possible sums of the `set` and your first number (so if your first number is 1 then your `set` contains 1 and 0)
3. Now add in the next number (so if your next number is 2 your `set` contains 0, 1, 2, and 3)
4. So on...

That `set` contains all possible numbers. You'll need to itterate through the `set` and find the first gap. This will work *even* if there are negative numbers in your set.

I know you said you just wanted the logic, but if you want to see a solution mouse over below:

> `set<int> foo{ 0 };`
>  `vector<int> numbers{ 4, 1, 2 };`
>
>  `for (auto& i : numbers){`
>  `set<int> temp;`
>
>  `for_each(foo.begin(), foo.end(),[&](int j){temp.insert(i + j);});`
>  `foo.insert(temp.begin(), temp.end());`
>  `}`
>
>  `for (auto& i : foo){`
>  `cout << i << endl;`
>  `}`
>  `cout << "First number that cannot be formed " << *mismatch(foo.begin(), prev(foo.end()), next(foo.begin()), [](int first, int second){return first + 1 == second;}).first + 1 << endl;`

If you're trying to implement the search for a gap in your `set` using an STL algorithm, I found that somewhat difficult. The problem is that you need to separate your iterator's incrementation from its comparison.

So for example this won't work:

> <strike>`auto i = foo.begin();`
>
>   `while (++i != prev(foo.end()) && *prev(i) + 1 == *i);`
>
>   `cout << "First number that cannot be formed " << *prev(i) + 1 << endl;`</strike>

Because if all numbers *are* sequential `*prev(i) + 1` is the last value in the set.

This option will work:

```
i = foo.begin();
while (i != prev(foo.end()) && *i + 1 == *next(i)){
    ++i;
}
cout << "First number that cannot be formed " << *i + 1 << endl;
```

But this assumes that your `set` always contains at least 0.

Answer (score 0):

The logic is to build all the possible sums for each successive integer, starting from 1.
The problem can be simplified by keeping track of all the possible sums and checking only for sums of pairs of integer. The pseudocode (untested and buggy) would look like:

```
const std::vector<unsigned> l = {1,2,4};
const unsigned sum = std::accumulate(l.begin(), l.end());
typedef std::vector<unsigned> Sum; // one possibility for a single value
typedef std::vector<Sum> Sums; // all possibilities for a single value
// the element all[i] will provide all possible subsets where the sum is equal to 'i'
std::vector<Sums> all(sum + 2); // we know that sum + 1 is impossible
// initialize with single values
for (auto i: l)
{
    all[i].push_back(Vector(1, i));
}
unsigned i = 1; // ignore 0
// stop as soon as a value doesn't have any subset
while (!all[i].empty())
{
    ++i;
    for (unsigned j = 1; i/2 > j; ++j)
    {
        const unsigned k = i - j;
        // as i == j+k, create all the relevant combinations
        for (const auto &sj: all[j])
        {
            for (const auto &sk: all[k])
            {
                all[i].push_back(sj);
                all[i].back.insert(all[i].end(), sk.begin(), sk.end());
            }
        }
    }
    if (0 == (i % 2))
    {
        // create all the possible decompositions out of i/2
        for (auto left = all[i/2].begin(); all[i/2].end() != left; ++left)
        {
            for (auto right = left + 1; all[i/2].end() != right; ++ right)
            {
                all[i].push_back(*left);
                all[i].back.insert(all[i].end(), right->begin(), right->end());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

One of the bugs that need to be addressed: rejecting sums where the same number appears more than once.

Answer (score 0):

For input `set`s or `multiset`s which only contain positive integers, [Evgeny Kluev's Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21079874/2642059) is *O(2n)*, [my other solution] is *O(nlogn)*.

For a given input `number`s you can find the unformable number as follows:

1. Collect elements of `number` into `int_log[i]` where `i = int(log2(`element`))`
2. Find `S[]` which is the prefix sum of `int_log[]`
3. The first unformable number is `S[x] + 1` where `int_log[x + 1]` contains no element less than or equal to `S[x] + 1`

For a proof that all numbers in the range *[0, `S[i]`]* can be formed by subset of `int_log` smaller than 2<sup>i-1</sup> see: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1099359/0-sum-representable-by-numbers-in-a-set

```
set<int> numbers{ 1, 2, 5, 6, 7 };
unordered_multimap<unsigned long, decltype(numbers)::key_type> int_log;

for (auto& value : numbers){
    auto key = decltype(int_log)::key_type{};

    _BitScanReverse(&key, value); //If using gcc you'll need to use __builtin_clz here
    int_log.insert(make_pair(key, value));
}

auto result = decltype(numbers)::key_type{}; // Because we only ever need to look at the previous prefix sum value we'll use previousSum instead of a S[] here
auto sum = decltype(numbers)::key_type{};
auto i = decltype(int_log)::key_type{};
auto smallest = decltype(numbers)::key_type{};

do{
    result = sum;
    smallest = 2 << i;

    for (auto range = int_log.equal_range(i); range.first != range.second; ++range.first){
        const auto current = range.first->second;

        sum += current;
        smallest = min(smallest, current);
    }
    ++i;
} while (result >= smallest - 1);
cout << "First number that cannot be formed: " << result + 1 << endl;
```